# How to apply Fault-Tolerance Algorithm using Cloudsim?

Tags: cloudsim

I want to create Fault tolerance algorithm using cloud Sim.

In this project basically I want to create data set  having the list of faults occur in system.( it’s predefine static list of some faults like authentication, VM failure, etc.) 
I want to create system which continuously check whether fault occur or on during scheduled task.

Can you help me regarding my project?
I want to know basically which algorithm should I apply and how will I implement in cloud Sim.

If there is any code related to my project it will more helpful me to go through my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try exploring WorkFlowSim simulator, it is an extension to cloudsim and it has provision for fault tolerance. Take a look at the following package in the workflowsim:-

package org.workflowsim.examples.failure.clustering;

Also refer to the following paper for getting some idea on the algorithm:-
https://scitech.isi.edu/wordpress/wp-content/papercite-data/pdf/chen-tcc-2015.pdf